# Checkbox validation error when usuing MVC 4 EditorFor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, editorfor

I am getting a strange checkbox validation error when the checkbox is selected. Error is on jquery.min: 
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

input:hidden[name='CategoriesandItems[1'].ChecklistItems[2].IsSelected]

Complex/Nested ViewModel

```
public class ChecklistVM
{        
    public int ChecklistId {get; set;}
    public string ChecklistName { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryandItemsVM> CategoriesandItems { get; set;     }       
}

public class CategoryandItemsVM
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<ChecklistItemVM> ChecklistItems { get; set; }
}

public class ChecklistItemVM
{   
    public int? ChecklistItemId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string PropName {gets; set;)
}
```

When I click the IsSelected CheckBox, I get the following syntax error. **Notice where the single quotes are placed.**

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
input:hidden[name='CategoriesandItems[1'].ChecklistItems[2].IsSelected]

**View**

```
 @model  ViewModels.CheckListVM

 @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.CategoriesandItems)

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
   window.validator = $("#ChecklistForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");    
    });
</script>
```

**EditorFor Template 1**

```
@model  ViewModels.CategoryandItemsVM        
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ChecklistItems)
```

**EditorFor Template 2**

```
@model  ViewModels.ChecklistItemVM        
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
```

If I loop through the nested collections manually (w/o EditorFor templates) and name the controls correctly everything works fine. It looks like there is a problem with the Kendo validator and nested models.

***UPDATE*** No resolution to this problem but I reproduced the problem with a less complex view model. The same error occurs when there is just 1 level of an EditorFor template.

Comment: Never figured out what the exact problem was but I was able to recreate the problem with a stripped down page. It's definitely related to the Kendo UI validator. I switched to the standard jQuery validator instead using. $('#formname').validate();